# height auto css works in FF but not IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, font-size

I have a background with sidebars. It contains the home , about steng. This is the widget in the red. I also have one that is in yellow. There is a drop down resizer and it is working in FF . If i go to 12, 16 , and 20. If i do this in IE the background image ( red circle and yellow ) is not auto adjusting. Does anyone know how to fix it. I though a min heigh and max height but unsure how to do that in CSS.

Here is the test site

http://wpcreations.net/wptest/

Thanks in advance. I been working on this for 2 hrs.

I need it to work in IE .

I did find out if i change the drop down and then refresh it looks like it adjusts. Anyone how how to get it to refresh. If someone can confirm if you hit F5 and refresh it works. I would love to figure out how to put a refresh in the code or if someone knows how to make it ajax.

Comment: Which version of IE? Looks fine in IE7. Although I'm not quick sure which background image you are referring to...

Comment: As a relevant note, there is much debate about having text resizing as part of your UX. In summary, recent shift has pushed to allow the browser or OS controls to handle this - they're going to do a far better job zooming. Your site potentially requires 508 compliance. In which case, you may be stuck. Nonetheless, I would encourage you to check and any future viewer to weigh this UX feature.

Comment: for the users that come to the site they usually always need help and i would love to do browsing zooming but do not know how to put that in a webpage. I am using IE 8. It is the red around the navigation bar and then the yellow

Comment: The counter-point would be that users who require increase text size are familiar with these controls or already made adjustments at the OS level. Looks fine in IE7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the div :

```
<li id="nav_menu-25" class="widget widget_nav_menu">

//remove
<div class="menu-sidebar-main-menu-container">
//this

<ul id="menu-sidebar-main-menu" class="menu">

...

</ul>

//and remove
</div>
//this

</li>
```

The "div" between "li" and "ul".

Doesn't seem to be doing anything, that's what is affecting ie, I've just tried it.

Comment: that is odd. I have tried IE 8 and showing issues with boxes overlapping . what do you mean about taking out that div ?

Comment: oh wish i could but that is part of wordpress widgitized area. I guess i am stuck with issue. I found on IE 8 i can refresh and it looks fine but the plugin i am using it is hard to tell where i can code a page refresh after a drop down